# Incompatible type warning on generic class method

Tags: java, generics

I have a generic class declared as follows:

```
class AdjMatrix<R extends Vertex, C extends Vertex> {
```

which has an array of `R` objects

```
private R[] rId = (R[]) new Object[size];
```

and the following method:

```
public R randR(){ return rId[rand.nextInt(rId.length)]; }
```

Assuming I have instantiated an instance of `AdjMatrix` as follows:

```
AdjMatrix<User, Item> matrix = new AdjMatrix<>(); //user and item extend vertex
```

shouldn't I be able to call `User u =  matrix.randR();`?

I'm getting an incompatible types warning that the method returns a Vertex.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do that without an error.  When I hack up some dummy classes as you've described it works for me.  What version of java are you using?

Comment: Should work. Try recompiling/rebuilding your project - you may be working with an old copy of the compiled class.